# How to get videos on Yahoo finance to play

Tags: video, streaming

Until a few months ago, these videos played ok in Firefox and Opera.

Then they stopped playing in Firefox

Now they don't play at all. Any ideas for a fix?

Comment: can you view youtube video?

Comment: Did the videos stop working at the same time you applied any system updates?

Comment: Try doing a "sudo apt-get update" and then a "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras".

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Chrome.  It has Flash built in.  Not Chromium.  Until Firefox and other browsers start doing this it will always be a hassle and I personally prefer to get work done rather then messing with a browser plugin.  I love Firefox, but I also have an Nvidia video card and the current Ubuntu installed Flash plugin has lots of issues.  Also Google adds patches faster then Adobe at times.

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/